# How to change PKCS12 keystore file from RSA1024 to RSA2048 and be able to update the app in Play Store?

Tags: android, java-8, google-play, rsa

More than 3 years ago we have started with our app on Play Store and we were using RSA1024 keystore .p12 file. However, since JDK 1.8_121 1024 bit keystore files are not supported by Oracle, so I cannot use newer java version to compile the app.

When I tried to create RSA2048 bit key file, it works, however I couldn't upload the update cause a "wrong developer information" or similar.

Any idea how to create 2048 bit key from 1024 bit key and to be recognized by Google Play Store?

Comment: 1024-bit keys work just fine with Java 8 keystores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have a key to sign your app, you can't change it. This is a restriction with Android, and not specific to Google Play. Changing your key is known as "Key rotation". Key rotation may be coming in the future [according to this article](https://www.xda-developers.com/apk-signature-scheme-v3-key-rotation/) but doesn't exist yet. I'd wait.

If you really need to do this, [a process which involves publishing a second app is described here](https://guardianproject.info/2015/12/29/how-to-migrate-your-android-apps-signing-key/).